# Как подружить webBrowser и Google Maps API?

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps-api, webbrowser

В других браузерах и в самом єксплорере все работает нормально, но вот в приложении, какая-то фигня. Если карту не трогать, то все ок, если начать двигать или скролить, то появляются такие ошибки:
https://pp.vk.me/c631327/v631327969/3400e/Y1ffT_Gz_6o.jpg
которые вылазят одна за другой, пока не закроешь программу, а если их отключить в настройках компонента, то просто карта зависает и не реагирует ни на что, пока не перезагрузишь страницу. А с маршрутами вообще беда, в браузере отрисовуются нормально, а тут такое:
https://pp.vk.me/c631327/v631327969/34007/6nGDwAcw4Vs.jpg
только маркеры и все, и не двигается, а если начать колесиком скролить, то маркеры пропадают вообще и карта все равно виснет.

Уже гуглил, нашел пару решений вставить  с какими-то параметрами совместимости, и прописать в реестре еще ключи с названием программы, в которой используется этот компонент, но ни то, ни то не помогло.

Comment: нужно прописать в реестре ключи и зайти на сайт типа "какой у меня браузер" и там будет видно правильно прописали ключи или нет.